# Trying to Get A Link Embedded in an HTML Page with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

On the webpage: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id979020229, there is a title that reads "Python at the US Federal Election Commission". When you click on that title, a link opens. What I'm trying to do is firstly, find the first title on the webpage that has an embedded link. Then, to get that link and print it. I'm not sure how to do this in Python, but I've tried using different ways I thought would work. One of the ways involved the BeautifulSoup module. My code is below.

Code:

```
page = requests.get(link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
eps = soup.find_all('a')
i = 0
while (len(open) < 1):
    s = str(eps[i].get('href'))
    if s[8] == 'q':
        open.append(s)
    i += 1
for i in open:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Your strategy consist in taking all links in an array, and then append it to the results? Why are you using "open" as a variable? "open" is a python reserved word, it is a function used to open files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use findall with the class of the link.

I used inspect element to determine which class to select, in this case, `tracks__track__link--block`

Then you can iterate through the links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id979020229')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
eps = soup.find_all(class_ = 'tracks__track__link--block')
for a in eps:
# gets the text of the link
    print(a.text)
# gets the link
    print(a['href'])
```

prints

```
      Python at the US Federal Election Commission

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/python-at-the-us-federal-election-commission/id979020229?i=1000522628049

      Flask 2.0

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/flask-2-0/id979020229?i=1000521751060

      Awesome FastAPI extensions and add ons

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/awesome-fastapi-extensions-and-add-ons/id979020229?i=1000520763681

      Ask us about modern Python projects and tools

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/ask-us-about-modern-python-projects-and-tools/id979020229?i=1000519506466

      Automate your data exchange with PyDantic

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/automate-your-data-exchange-with-pydantic/id979020229?i=1000518286844

      Python Apps that Scale to Billions of Users

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/python-apps-that-scale-to-billions-of-users/id979020229?i=1000517664109
```